# C# - sending, reciving and then sending again via a socket

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

Me and my friend are making a basic client/server application, on two different computers.  What we are trying to do :

1.I send him a string (as a server)

2 He sends me back another string,

3. I edit it and send it back.

But everytime we got to part 3 he doesn't recive anything my software just stops working and via debugging I end up with

```
"{"A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call"}
```

I'm pretty sure the fault is on my end, here are the functions that i'm  using:

```
private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        //  handler.Close();
        sendDone.Set();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
       // Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = s.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            s.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.

            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

I connet with the client via

```
  IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("my_actual_ip_adress");
        // use local m/c IP address, and 
        // use the same in the client

        /* Initializes the Listener */
        TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

        /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
        myList.Start();
```

I realise that it probably sounds like a silly issue but we're having hard time coming up with actual solution, any help would me much appreciated

Comment: Why are you calling `handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);`? It does what it says.

Comment: The client doesn't recieve the first string If I comment the line or try any version of SocketShutDown

Comment: I managed to fix it! Turns out we needed get rid of handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both) and then change how the client recieve the data, since he was waiting for the socket to shutdown. Thanks setting me along the right path @JeroenvanLangen

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it! Turns out we needed get rid of handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both) and then change how the client recieve the data, since he was waiting for the socket to shutdown.
– some